# TypeScript 2.0 created JS files are ignored on publishing to Azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, typescript2.0

## Scenario

I'm using **VisualStudio 2015** to create a Webservice containing TypeScript.

I'm currently using **TypeScript Version 2.03** and the compilation is processed by the [**Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild**] NuGet package.

Common project tree:

[image: Common project tree]

## What is working

I can normal compile and run my webproject locally without any error or problems.
All ***.ts** file will be translated into ***.js** files.

Example from the project directory:

[image: directory]

## What is not working

If I want to create an Azure package (**cspkg** file) or to direct publish my project to Azure, all ***.ts** to ***.js** compiled files are not included.

Normal (pure) ***.js** files are include!

## What I have done so far

- I take a look into the **[C:\AzureTmp]** directory and all compile TypeScript files are missed
- I take a look into the verbose log output and see that the **tsc.exe** is called without errors

[image: output1]

- I switched the NuGet package version of [**Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild**] back to **1.8.11** and all ***.js** gets **included as expected**
- I switched the NuGet package version of [**Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild**] up to **2.06** and all ***.js** gets are **not** included again

## Question

Why are compiled TypeScript file created with [**Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild**] Version >= 2.03 not moved to the **[C:\AzureTmp]** directory and in result not included inside the Azure package (**cspkg** file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

This line:

`<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />`

in the project file was near the end of the file.

Just open the project file in a text editor and moved it up near the top.
Note, the new spot should be above the TypeScript configuration nodes in the project file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b329021-cd7a-4a01-86fc-714c2d05bb6c ?

Without changing anything in your solution, just be sure that "Remove addition files at destination" is not checked in your publishing profile > Settings > File Publish Options.

Comment: No I'm using the normal MSBuilder

Comment: So, did you try to change your publishing settings ?